# How to change separation between tick labels and axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, spacing

My axis labels often look not good (too close to tick labels) when I use Matplotlib.

[image: test image]

How to set distance between tick labels and axis label? I just need to enlarge distance between "Number of stars" label and corresponding tick labels. Maybe latex `\vspace{}` is working but I don't know how to implement it. `fig.subplots_adjust(left=)` is not a solution.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the `labelpad` parameter in the [`ax.set_ylabel()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel) method. This takes a number of points to be used as spacing between the axis and the corresponding label.

Comment: Thank you!!! Write this as answer.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same for 'drawparallels' in Basemap (Matplotlib)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To move the axis label further away from the axis, you can include an argument to the optional `labelpad` parameter of the corresponding method used to set the label, i.e. [`ax.set_ylabel()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel) or [`ax.set_xlabel()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel). This parameter takes a scalar which is the spacing between the axis and the label given in *points*.

As to achieve the same effect when using the [`drawparallels()`](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawparallels) method of **Basemap**, I believe you can include an argument to the parameters `xoffset` or `yoffset`, depending on which axis you want to alter the placement of the text. The arguments of these parameters have "units" of *map width*, meaning e.g. `xoffset=0.05` makes the offset of the x-ticks 5 % of the map width.

Comment: Rolled back to my original answer, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/223330) for more info as to why.

Comment: while this answer was satisfactory for the questioner, it is not entirely right: labelpad does *not* set the distance between the axis and the axis label, it sets the distance between the tick labels and the axis label.

Answer (score 5):

This is a *really* subjective question, but I'll take a stab anyway:

The `figsize` kwarg takes the width and height of the figure in inches.

A4 paper is 8.3" by 11.7". So let's say, for the sake of argument, you want 1" margins.

```
paperheight = 11.7
paperwidth = 8.3
margin = 1.0

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(paperwidth - 2*margin, paperheight - 2*margin))

# plotting stuff

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig(...)
```

The call to `tight_layout()` will give the labels a bit more room and make sure that everything is expanded out to the figure edges as much as practicable.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my question.

Comment: @user2579566 I see that. It doesn't change my answer however. Simply change `paperheight` and `paperwidth` as needed and change `margin` as desired

Comment: @user2579566 can you be more specific? works on my end.

Comment: My axes labels overlap figures when a I use your values (11.7,8.3,1.0)

Comment: @user2579566 It's going to be impossible to diagnose until you show the code you're using. Are you calling `fig.tight_layout()?`

Comment: Yes I do. I just need to enlarge distance between left "Number of stars" labels and corresponding pictures. I use usual fig.add_subplot() and plot() functions.

Comment: @user2579566 I simply cannot make any further suggestions until you provide a short, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem you're seeing. I started it for you in my response. All you need to do is fill in your part where it says `# plotting stuff` (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46711/discussion-between-paul-h-and-user2579566)